# what does this notation $Z1\{condition\}$ mean?

Tags: probability, notation

I am reading that you can decompose a random variable like this:

$$
Z = Z1\{Z\leq\theta\mathbb{E}[Z]\} + Z1\{Z>\theta\mathbb{E}[Z]\}
$$

What does $$Z1\{condition\} $$ mean in this case?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1_{\{condition\}}$ is an indicator function: $1$ when condition is true, $0$ when it is not.
$Z 1_{\{condition\}}$ is just the random variable $Z$ multiplied by this.

Comment: The decomposition is thus:$$Z~\mathbf 1_{\{Z\leq \theta\,\Bbb E[Z]\}}+Z~\mathbf 1_{\{Z > \theta\,\Bbb E[Z]\}}=\begin{cases} Z&\text{if}& Z\leq \theta\,\Bbb E[Z]\\[1ex] Z&\text{if}& Z>\theta\,\Bbb E[Z]\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!. It is clear for me now.